# How to replace (blah) with {blah} for a specific string

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

In a latex document, I wish to  replace \cost(blah) with \cost{blah} in the entire document, where blah is an arbitrary string.  That is, I only want to change the round brackets to curly brackets for every expression involving \cost. I realize this involves regular expressions in emacs - but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `query-replace-regexp` (bound to `C-M-%` by default), which prompts for a regexp and a replacement, then asks for confirmation at each match (useful for preventing accidents).

The regex you want to type in is `\\cost(\(.*\))`, and the replacement should be `\\cost{\1}`.

The key is to understand the regexp syntax. Most characters in the regexp stand for themselves; a `c` in the regexp just matches a “c” in the buffer. Characters that have some special meaning are mostly prefixed with a backslash, so matching a backslash requires a double–backslash. Thus the regexp `\\cost()` simply matches the string “\cost()” in the buffer.

Inside the parens is going to be some text that can vary. We want to capture that text and use it in the replacement, so we will surround it with parens, but these must be parens with backslashes: `\(\)`. This makes a capturing group.

Inside the group we just want to match anything. A period (`.`) matches any single character, and an asterisk (`*`) modifies the previous item so that it matches zero or more of the same thing. Thus `.*` is a basic regexp trick to match any number of any thing of character.

When we put it all together we get `\\cost(\(.*\))`. Note that the capturing parens are inside the normal parens, so that the normal parens are not captured.

Finally, in the replacement we again use `\\` to mean a single backslash character, and `\1` to mean the contents of the first capturing group in the regexp.

I recommend practicing this in the regexp builder, which lets you see exactly what a regexp matches as you type it in; it also shows you what every capturing group matches. First, put some sample text in your scratch buffer, like this:

```
\cost{blah}
\cost{foo}
\stuff(blah)
\cost{bar}
\cost{123}
```

Then run the regexp builder by typing `M-x re-builder`. This opens a small buffer below the scratch buffer where you can type in a regexp. One thing to note is that you are typing this into an elisp string, as if you were writing a program. Elisp strings also use the backslash character for escaping, so every backslash has to be doubled. Type this in:

```
\\\\cost(\\(.*\\))
```

As you type it in, watch as the regex matches change in the scratch buffer. When you complete the group, you’ll see them highlighted in a different color. To exit the regexp builder, type `C-x C-q`.

I recommend reading [chapter 15.6 Syntax of Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) in the Emacs manual, as it documents everything that can go in a regexp. You can open the Info viewer to read the manuals inside of Emacs by typing `C-h i`.

Then go practice some regexes!

Comment: Just a word of caution: Emacs regexes match greedily.  If the line containing `blah` has other expressions with a ")" after `blah`, then this my have unintended consequences.  E.g. It would replace `$\cos(t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function (because I say so)` with `$\cos{t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function (because I say so}`.  The first is valid LaTeX code, and the second is not...

Comment: Thanks, yes, I noticed this. I have some latex equations containing "\cost(a)   \inf ( ) "  and the replace regexp converts it to "\cost{a) \inf( }"  which is not what I want. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Comment: Yes, use a non–greedy match inside the capture group, `.*?`, or use the safer method `[^)]*`, which is a character class that matches everything except the close–paren.

Comment: Sorry this is not clear to me.  Should I use \\cost(\(.*?\))  and replacement \\cost{\1}  That does not work.

Comment: Go back and read the part about backslashes again; you want `\\cost(\(.*?\))`.

Comment: Great answer. I had a very different replacement but your clear instruction really helped me solve the issue.